# Hudson plugin. Where is it?

Tags: hudson, tuleap

I have installed new version of tuleap and noticed that hudson installs as plugin. I assumed that hudson now comes as a plugin and we don't need to install it.

Am i Right? I cant find it. or do i still need to set it up the usual way?

Answer (score 0):

The hudson plugin only allow bridging between Tuleap and an existing Hudson or Jenkins server.

So, you need to install jenkins as usual